# Model instance replaced with remote method result in Angular call to Loopback

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I have a Loopback API with an Angular front end, and have been seeing some strange behavior when trying to call a non-static remote method.

I've boiled it down to this example. When making a call like this:

```
$scope.myInstance = MyModel.findOne({}, function success(value){
  $scope.greeting = value.$prototype$hello({}, function success(){});
});
```

I'm finding that $scope.myInstance ends up containing the result of the call to $prototype$hello and $scope.greeting is empty. MyModel is defined with a remote call like this:

```
module.exports = function(MyModel) {

   MyModel.prototype.hello = function(cb) {
     cb(null,"Hello: " + this.name);
   }

   MyModel.remoteMethod(
     'hello',
     {
       isStatic: false,
       http: { verb: 'get' },
       returns: {arg: 'message', type: 'string'}
     }
   );

};
```

So if I have this in my template:

```
Greeting = {{ greeting }}, Instance = {{ myInstance }}
```

I see:

> Greeting = {}, Instance = {"message":"Hello: Test","$promise":{},"$resolved":true}

With the greeting result clearly in place of the model instance. I would expect to see the model instance in the Instance variable:

> Greeting = {}, Instance = Instance = {"name":"Test","id":1,"$promise":{},"$resolved":true}

There is a brief flash of the model during loading.

I can work around this by retrieving additional throwaway instances of the model, but I'm hoping someone knows why this is happening and if there's a cleaner solution.

**UPDATE 08/12/2015:** I've created a Plunker to demonstrate this problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCAIluDBHVSp1lpShaiZ), but this only contains the client-side JS. For the full loopback project, I've added the code to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/theothertomelliott/LoopbackAngularModelIssue)

Interestingly enough, the behavior is slightly different under Safari, which doesn't render the instance at all:

> Greeting = {}, Instance =

The originally described behavior was seen under Chrome.

Comment: Create a plunker or fiddle so that we can actually help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, see my update. Please note that this is a Loopback (Node.js) project, so a Plunker will only show the client-side portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your plunker, and I think I got the issue here, your code is:

```
$scope.myInstance = MyModel.findOne({}, function success(value){
  $scope.greeting = value.$prototype$hello({}, function success(){});
});
```

let's forget about the success function for a second, `findone()` function returns your requested document from a mongodb, as I think, which means, naturally, the returned document or query will be stored in `$scope.myInstance`, which is how your app is behaving. 
Now for the success function, it's trying to call `value.$prototype$hello` which doesn't exist in the response object (value), so the value is `undefined` and that gets stored in the `$scope.greeting` that's why it is displaying as empty.

why `$prototype$hello` is `undefined` is simple, it's a prototype object if it was a part of your app but you are trying to access this function through a response object that doesn't have it.

I hope this answers your question

### EDIT:

the problem is with this line

```
 $scope.greeting = value.$prototype$hello({}, function success(){});
```

just make like this:

```
value.$prototype$hello({}, function success(val){$scope.greeting = val.message;},function error(err){console.log(err);});
```

### Edit 2

change your code to be like this:

```
ModelA.findOne({}, function success(value){
  //debugger;
  value.$prototype$hello({}, function success(val){$scope.greeting = val.message;},function error(err){console.log(err);});
}).$promise.then(function(res) {
  $scope.myInstance = res;
});
```

this way, you will not have bogus data in your variable before the promise is resolved.
And, it's purely normal for the response object to have $promise, and $resolved attributes, because it's a resource promise object

### EDIT 3

now after you clarified the issue on your last comment, I was able to understand it, I was looking for something else, but anyway they are related.
what was happening is a conflict, you are doing two async calls, you should treat them that way, this is how the code should be:

```
ModelA.findOne({}).$promise.then(function(value) {
  $scope.myInstance = value;
  var v2 = angular.copy(value);
  v2.$prototype$hello({},
    function (val){
      $scope.greeting = val.message;
    },
    function (err){console.log(err);}
  );
});
```

let me know if you need more input regarding the code

Comment: The result of findOne is being stored in $scope.myInstance briefly, but this is quickly replaced by the result of $prototype$hello (which does exist).

Is there a different way I should be accessing $prototype$hello(..)? I'm not too familiar with resource handling in Angular.

Comment: As a side note, I found $prototype$hello by adding a debugger line and putting a watch on `value`.

Comment: not sure why i was down voted, anyway, found out the issue, check the edit

Comment: Did you run your suggested edit in the plunker? This set the greeting correctly, but `$scope.myInstance` is still set to the promise returned by `value.$prototype$hello`, when it should be the result of the `findOne` call.

Comment: no no you got this wrong, angular resources have promises in them, when you do a remote call for a resource you will have a promise object in return that is totally normal, and the proper way is to use response.$promise.then(function(){async code goes here}) to run your code asynchronously, check the edit

Comment: I'm not bothered about having the promise included in the output. I ran your second edit and still get `Instance = {"message":"Hello: Test","$promise":{},"$resolved":true}` in the output. Which is wrong (value of the message). I'm expecting it to be: `Instance = {"name":"Test","id":1,"$promise":{},"$resolved":true}` (value of the ModelA instance).

Comment: now that I understood your problem, check my latest edit, i think that's what you want

Comment: Still seeing the same output with Edit 3, unfortunately. Not sure about what's going on under the hood, but since success isn't called until the promise is resolved, wouldn't using then effectively be doing the same thing?

Comment: finally it's stable, the issue was the $prototype$hello was overriding 'value' if you clone it before using the function it solves the issue, the updated code is in edit 3

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. Although I'm curious as to why the only way to access hello is via a prototype, when other similarly defined methods can be accessed directly on the instance (see lbservice.js). Guess that's one for the loopback developers.